# Within UIViewController class, @IBOutlet self.tableView is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController (FiltersViewController) with 2 components in storyboard, UITableView and UIStackView as following:

[image]

```
class FiltersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView! // PROBLEM: this is nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView // is always nil
    }

    func someFunc() {
        self.tableView // is always nil
    }
}
```

I am adding `FiltersViewController.view` to current UIViewController as following:

```
class CurrentViewController: UIViewController {

    let floatingView: UIView = UIView()
    var filtersViewController = FiltersViewController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        floatingView.frame = CGRectMake(-201, 0, 270, 270)
        floatingView.clipsToBounds = false
        self.view.addSubview(floatingView)

        floatingView.addSubview(filtersViewController.view)
    }
}
```

It works, if I only change the FiltersViewController to subclass UITableViewController, as following:

```
class FiltersViewController: UITableViewController {
```

But, another problem with this change, `Stack View` is missing

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, i have double checked, uploading screenshot now

Comment: Why do you use a `UIViewController` to add a subview instead of subclassing a `UIView` (or any other object) and then adding the controller to the current view controller?

Comment: @PabloA. I ended up with something similar, got rid of `UIViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with creating separate UIView in xib (separate from main.storyboard), and instantiate as following:

```
let filtersView = UINib(nibName: "Filters", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
```

after view being instantiated, add it as subview

```
floatingView.addSubview(filtersView)
```

`@IBOutlet`'s are connected and works like charm!

Answer (score 2):

Problem here:`var filtersViewController = FiltersViewController()`. You need to initialize your controller by passing nib to `init` method.

Change the property declaration,

```
var filtersViewController: FiltersViewController?
```

To load from a storyboard, you should do this in viewDidLoad

```
filtersViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourFilterViewControllerIdentifier")
floatingView.addSubview(filtersViewController.view)
```

Comment: I am having the same problem but it is giving me an error "Cannot asign value of UIViewController to UITableViewController", although my View is UIViewController

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain It is because in your `Storyboard` you've placed `UITableViewController` instance, not `UIViewController`.